# It is said that namespaces IN XML are just to avoid name conflicts but that doesnt seem to be true

Tags: xml, xslt

When using an XSLT file linked to an XML file - it works fine to extract and show the data in XHTML, but if I change the namespace name from "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" to anything else it does not work - why?

Answer (score 0):

"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" is the XSLT namespace. *"XSLT processors must use the XML namespaces mechanism to recognize elements and attributes from this namespace."* http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#xslt-namespace

Without this, there would be no way for an XSLT processor to differentiate between:

`<template xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">`

which is an XSLT instruction, and:

`<template xmlns="http://example.com">`

which is a literal result element to be passed to the output tree. http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#literal-result-element

So it *could* be said that the purpose here is to avoid name conflicts too - although I am not sure that's the best way to characterize namespaces in general.